# Mongo analog to SQL query

Tags: mongodb

This in `SQL` query:

```
select * from t where (f1 = 1 and f2 = 2) or (f1 = 2 and f2 = 3) or (f1 = 3 and f2 = 3)
```

How to find this records in mongodb using one query?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Read docs, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query is equivalent to your SQL:

```
db.t.find({$or:[{f1:1, f2:2}, {f1:2, f2:3}, {f1:3, f2:3}]})
```

But like @u_mulder said, you could have easily found the solution had you tried to google or look at mongodb docs.